# Facebook API "Like" discrepancy

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

This is my app page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/When-Biebs-Attack/402350233140999
As you can see, it's an actual "App Page", created from my app control panel.  So you would assume it would be linked with the app.

Now here is the (only) site that uses the App ID for a like button: http://cosmati.net/biebsattack/

Not only is the discrepancy weird, but as soon as I added the like button to the page it had 22 likes.  I have double checked my App ID in my code.  It does line up with my app control panel.  I tried both the HTML5 and the XFBML methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I don't know why it's doing what it's doing, but I figured out you can link them directly by adding an href tag to the like button and pointing it to the url of your facebook page.  For instance, my like button now looks like this:

```
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/When-Biebs-Attack/402350233140999" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

And now when I visit my site (http://cosmati.net/biebsattack/), not only do I only see 1 like (mine), but I see links to administer my page and view insights.  Kind of neat.  Not sure why it doesn't do this by default when I use the App ID, but whatever.